# Get a substring from a marker and the next 200 characters after the marker

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a long string and I have only one marker that I can use "\Guest" and I want the next 200 characters after it finds "\Guest". So far, I tried splicing in different ways, but nothing sticks.. My code is the following:

```
string_start = data.find(r"\Guest")
string_end = data.find(+200, string_start)
full_string = data[string_start:string_end]
print("string testing: ", full_string)
```

Where data is the long input string. Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Can you add the _long input string_?

Comment: Have you tried `data[string_start+6:string_start+6+200]`?

Comment: @Idlehands I just tried it. It works perfectly. If you submit an answer, I will mark it as the correct solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

`data[string_start+6:string_start+6+200]`

Where 6 is the length of your `'\Guest'` string.  You could scale it easily:

```
keyword = r'\Guest'
string_start = data.find(keyword) + len(keyword)
result = data[string_start: string_start + 200]
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on the comment from @Idlehands, you're getting the start position of the marker "\Guest" in `string_start`, so you could extract the substring with

```
string_start = date.find(r'\Guest') + len(r'\Guest')  # the position after "\Guest"
string_end = string_start + 200
full_string = data[string_start:string_end]
```